# Change Registration form in Joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, registration, custom-fields

I am developing a website where I need to create two user types. One is "member" and the other is "merchant". Both have different areas to be accessed. I am really confused on how can I achieve this.

Also I am trying to add my custom fields of First name and Password in the default Joomla registration form. As soon as I add a new TR with field first name the registration form stops working.

Can you guys help me in doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have some troubles with default Joomla registrtion, you could use [Community Builder](http://www.joomlapolis.com/community-builder). It is pretty easy to add fields to users profile and users registration. To separate members and merchants you could add field to the registration form called for example `Account type`. And then according to its value assign new user as `registered`(members) or `author`(merchant).

Comment: This does not address how control access would be controlled. Setting a CB extra field to member or merchant does not regulate what content a particular user type would have access to.

Answer (score 0):

First, adding user types in 1.5 is not going to accomplish the access requirements you have described. You would need to install an access control component to control different user types accessing different content.

Next, Joomla 1.5 is nearing end of life, April 2012 to be exact. Version 1.7.x released last week so you should very seriously consider moving the site to the latest version. An added bonus is that Joomla 1.7.x has built in access control levels that would accomplish what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding different access levels best thing to do would be upgrade to Joomla 1.6/1.7 It has this functionality built in. It may be possible to achieve this in 1.5 with third party components, but I don't have any experience with this.

Regarding custom registration fields, again, if you upgrade to 1.6/1.7 it has **User - Profile** plugin which allows to add additional fields to your registration form.
In 1.5 you can use third party components such as ExtendedReg (commercial).
Or alternately edit core files: http://www.mysysadmintips.com/index.php/web/100